# Querying Prolog variables with JPL

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I want to make a query to use Prolog in java through JPL, I read the documentation (http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/java_api/getting_started.html)
The prolog predicates are these:

```
child_of(joe, ralf).
child_of(mary, joe).
child_of(steve, joe).
child_of(steve, ralf).

descendent_of(X, Y) :-
    child_of(X, Y).
descendent_of(X, Y) :-
    child_of(Z, Y),
descendent_of(X, Z).
```

My code looks like this

```
Variable X = new Variable();

        Query q4 =
            new Query(
                "descendent_of",
                new Term[] {X,new Atom("joe")}
            );

        java.util.Hashtable solution;

        while ( q4.hasMoreSolutions() ){
            solution = q4.nextSolution();
            System.out.println( "X = " + solution.get(X));
        }
```

According to my prolog predicates, my java code should retrieve 'mary' and 'steve', but I get this:

```
X = null
X = null
```

What I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance

**EDIT**: this is my entire testing

```
Query q1 =
    new Query(
        "consult",
        new Term[] {new Atom("C:\\Users\\cardozo\\Documents\\fer\\info2\\lore\\test.pl")}
    );

return q1;

System.out.println( "consult " + (q.query() ? "succeeded" : "failed"));

Query q2 =
    new Query(
        "child_of",
        new Term[] {new Atom("joe"),new Atom("X")}
    );
Boolean resp= q2.query();
System.out.println("child_of(joe,X) is " + resp.toString()
);

Query q3 =
    new Query(
        "descendent_of",
        new Term[] {new Atom("steve"),new Atom("ralf")}
    );

System.out.println(
    "descendent_of(joe,ralf) is " +
    ( q3.query() ? "provable" : "not provable" )
);

Variable X = new Variable();

Query q4 =
    new Query(
        "descendent_of",
        new Term[] {X,new Atom("joe")}
    );

java.util.Hashtable solution;

q4.query();

while ( q4.hasMoreSolutions() ){
    solution = q4.nextSolution();
    System.out.println( "X = " + solution.get("X"));
}
```

And this is what I get in my java console as result

```
run:
% C:\Users\cardozo\Documents\fer\info2\lore\test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 8 clauses
consult succeeded
child_of(joe,X) is false
descendent_of(joe,ralf) is provable
X = null
X = null
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: I do not see you filling the database. See **consult** on that page.

Comment: @JoopEggen consult is not only for open the prolog file? I open my pl file previously using the Query class listed in that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to get variable by name:

```
solution.get("X")
```

**edit**

with a literal query like

Query q4 = new Query("descendent_of(X,joe)")

Comment: sorry for the delay, I had some minor trouble in setup JPL

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, I have to use the class Compound (included in jpl) like this

```
Query q4 = new Query(new Compound("descendent_of", new Term[] { new Variable("X"), new Atom("joe")}));

while ( q4.hasMoreSolutions() ){
            solution = q4.nextSolution();
            System.out.println( "X = " + solution.get("X"));
        }
```

And I get the solution

```
X = mary
X = steve
```