# Querying Prolog with multiple results in JPL

Tags: java, netbeans, prolog, stack-overflow, jpl

I want to build a knowledge base for an AI in Prolog. First I want to try to learn Prolog and it's uses by doing a toy example with elephants, giant ants etc.

I am using: NetBeans 8.0.1, SWI-Prolog 6.6.6 and Windows 8.1. Everything is 64-bits and the environment variables are correctly setup. I have also linked to the `jpl.jar` in my NetBeans library.

My Prolog knowledge base looks like this:

```
bigger(elephant, horse).
bigger(horse, donkey).
bigger(donkey, dog).
bigger(donkey, monkey).
bigger(monkey, ant).
bigger(monkey, dog).
bigger(giant_ant, elephant).

is_bigger(X, Y) :- bigger(X, Y).
is_bigger(X, Y) :- bigger(X, Z), is_bigger(Z, Y).
```

Inspired by [this](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/u.endriss/teaching/prolog/prolog.pdf).
The knowledge base works without any errors in SWI-Prolog.

When trying to get the multiple answers when X is bigger than ant in Java, however, I run into a stack overflow error.

This is snippets from my Java code where JPL is being used.

```
Query q1 =
    new Query(
        "consult",
        new Term[] {new Atom("pathToFile\\bigger.pl")}
    );

System.out.println( "consult " + (q1.query() ? "succeeded" : "failed"));

Query q2 =
    new Query(
        "bigger",
        new Term[] {new Atom("giant_ant"),new Atom("elephant")}
    );
Boolean resp= q2.query();
System.out.println("bigger(elephant, horse) is " + resp.toString());

Query q3 =
    new Query(
        "is_bigger",
        new Term[] {new Atom("giant_ant"),new Atom("ant")}
    );

System.out.println(
    "is_bigger(giant_ant, ant) is " +
    ( q3.query() ? "provable" : "not provable" )
);

Query q4 = new Query("is_bigger(X, ant)");

java.util.Hashtable solution;

q4.query();

while ( q4.hasMoreSolutions() ){
    solution = q4.nextSolution();
    System.out.println( "X = " + solution.get("X"));
}
```

The Java code was mostly taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494747/querying-prolog-variables-with-jpl).

From what I can get out from the debugger in NetBeans the stack overflow error seems to happen when Java is trying to determine the value of `solution.get("X")` at the end of the code snippet.

This is what my console output looks like:

```
consult succeeded
bigger(elephant, horse) is true
is_bigger(giant_ant, ant) is provable
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at jpl.Term.getTerm(Term.java:614)
at jpl.Term.getTerm(Term.java:652)
at jpl.Term.getTerm(Term.java:652)
at jpl.Term.getTerm(Term.java:652)
at jpl.Term.getTerm(Term.java:652)
at jpl.Query.get1(Query.java:334) (and many more like this.)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'll gladly provide more information if needed.

Comment: have you tried increasing the stack size for java? The `-ss` and `-oss` flags might come in handy.

Comment: Using -ss to increase stack size seems to make the program freeze indefinetly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get it to run JPL on my machine anymore, but from looking at the docs you might want to use a `Variable` object and construct your query like your did for `q3`:

```
Variable X = new Variable("X");
Query   q4 = new Query("is_bigger", new Term[]{X, new Atom("ant")});

while ( q4.hasMoreElements() ) {
 java.util.Hashtable solution = (Hashtable) q4.nextElement();
 System.out.println( "X = " + (Term) solution.get("X"));
}
```

Comment: Doing this seems to hide the error. Instead of having the stack overflow error in the console I get five instances (the correct amount of solutions!) of X = null. However if I use break points and try to "manually" see what the solution stored is I get the same stack overflow error after a while in the box where the value should be displayed. I also tried using Compound like in the second solution in the thread I linked to in my question, same error.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow lost attention of this answer. I edited in an possible solution. JPL sill isn't running in my machine. But you'll have to name the variable for sure.